# Invoking SQL Notebook with Markdown, from a Python Notebook causes a "Parse Exception"

Tags: azure, apache-spark, databricks

I'm running into an oddity in Azure Databricks, where I'm no longer able to `%run` a SQL notebook, if it contains markdown commands.

Does anyone know of a workaround, beyond removing the markdown commands?

For additional context, these SQL notebooks, tend to generate Temporary Views that might be shared by multiple other notebooks.

Ran this test on an older 10.4LTS cluster, as well as a newer 11.2 cluster. Same results on both clusters. The issue corresponds with the recent databricks UI change.

**Steps to Recreate:**

1. Create SQL notebok ('Test_SubNotebook')

   - Cmd1. Enter a basic SQL command (e.g. `select 'Test'`)
2. Create Python Notebook ('Test_Notebook')

   - Cmd1. Enter the command:  `%run './Test_SubNotebook'`
3. Run 'Test_Notebook', it will succed (showing a basic dataframe Table)

Now to demonstrate the issue

1. Add a new Command to 'Test_SubNotebook'

   - Cmd2. Enter

     ```
     %md
     Test Markdown
     ```

Now re-run 'Test_Notebook', it will fail, listing:

```
Test Markdown
ParseException:
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParseException                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-994671275763904> in <module>
      5     display(df)
      6     return df
----> 7   _sqldf = ____databricks_percent_sql()
      8 finally:
      9   del ____databricks_percent_sql

<command-994671275763904> in ____databricks_percent_sql()
      2   def ____databricks_percent_sql():
      3     import base64
----> 4     df = spark.sql(base64.standard_b64decode("JW1kClRlc3QgTWFya2Rvd24=").decode())
      5     display(df)
      6     return df

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in sql(self, sqlQuery)
    775         [Row(f1=1, f2='row1'), Row(f1=2, f2='row2'), Row(f1=3, f2='row3')]
    776         """
--> 777         return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
    778 
    779     def table(self, tableName):

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    121                 # Hide where the exception came from that shows a non-Pythonic
    122                 # JVM exception message.
--> 123                 raise converted from None
    124             else:
    125                 raise

ParseException: 
mismatched input '%' expecting {'(', 'APPLY', 'CONVERT', 'COPY', 'OPTIMIZE', 'RESTORE', 'ADD', 'ALTER', 'ANALYZE', 'CACHE', 'CLEAR', 'COMMENT', 'COMMIT', 'CREATE', 'DELETE', 'DESC', 'DESCRIBE', 'DFS', 'DROP', 'EXPLAIN', 'EXPORT', 'FROM', 'GRANT', 'IMPORT', 'INSERT', 'LIST', 'LOAD', 'LOCK', 'MAP', 'MERGE', 'MSCK', 'REDUCE', 'REFRESH', 'REPLACE', 'RESET', 'REVOKE', 'ROLLBACK', 'SELECT', 'SET', 'SHOW', 'START', 'SYNC', 'TABLE', 'TRUNCATE', 'UNCACHE', 'UNLOCK', 'UPDATE', 'USE', 'VALUES', 'WITH'}(line 1, pos 0)

== SQL ==
%md
^^^
Test Markdown
```

Comment: I have reproduced this and getting the same as above. But when calling from python Notebook to Python Notebook it is working fine.

Comment: Thanks @RakeshGovindula - I'm seeing the same thing. I'm curious if this is a recent bug, that was deployed in Azure Dbx. 
Converting our "sub" notebooks to .py, might be the solution to move forward.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue that is unrelated to dbr versions. The cause for the issue was due to a relatively new feature "implicit df" where we would generate a pyspark dataframe when you are running sql cells within python notebooks.

We've had a fix already which will be out in 3.82 release. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Here's the documentation for the implicit df feature: https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebooks-use.html#implicit-sql-df